# How to initiate the learning process of modern day IT Security concepts mainly cryptography?

Tags: cryptography, career, professional-education

I am a programmer with about 7 years of experience mainly in Java . I am interested in the subject of cryptography very much . I love algorithms and datastructures . When I first started learning about Algorithms , I found the book [Introduction to Algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/) by CLRS really really helpful . Then I picked up [Steven Skienna's book - the Algorithm Design Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000693) which built upon the concepts presented in CLRS.

While studying up on IT Security I would like to do it in a similar systematic way . Can you Gurus please guide me on how to get started with IT Security,mainly cryptography . Any books , resources that I should pick up first before diving into more specific topics ?

Comment: Hi Geek, welcome to [security.se]. This is not a great fit for our site, its jus asking for a list of books - see the [faq]. But look around, you may find other books mentioned elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practical Cryptography by Bruce Schneier is an interesting read if you're interested in how cryptography works and the evolution of protocols. It's not a programming reference, which may be good or bad depending on what you are looking to learn.

Comment: @GdP can you please provide the link to this book ? Is it [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Cryptography-Niels-Ferguson/dp/0471223573) ?

Comment: @Geek, that's the one.